# How can i pass store code to the url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

i want to pass store code to the url but not with "Add Store Code to Urls" inbuilt feature because it gives warning " Warning! When using Store Code in URLs, in some cases system may not work properly if URLs without Store Codes are specified in the third-party services (e.g. PayPal etc.)."
So please give me any other solution that can be implement with the admin pannel

Comment: Hi, first I wanted to know you are using multi store or not?

Comment: yes , i'm using

Answer (score 1):

**Create an View Model :**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

class AllWebsite implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\CollectionFactory $websiteCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_websiteCollectionFactory = $websiteCollectionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

     /**
     * Retrieve websites collection of system
     *
     * @return Website Collection
     */
    public function getWebsiteCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_websiteCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Baseurl
     *
     * @return Baseurl
     */
    public function getbaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

**Add a code in default.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="store_switcher">
    <arguments>
       <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\AllWebsite</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Create file app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Store/templates/switch/stores.phtml**

```
  <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Store\Block\Switcher $block */
$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
$websites  = $viewModel->getWebsiteCollection();
$baseUrl   = $viewModel->getbaseUrl();
?>
<?php if (count($block->getGroups())>1) : ?>
<div class="switcher store switcher-store" id="switcher-store">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Select Store')) ?></span></strong>
    <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getGroups() as $_group) : ?>
            <?php if ($_group->getId() == $block->getCurrentGroupId()) : ?>
                <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
                     role="button"
                     tabindex="0"
                     data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
                     data-toggle="dropdown"
                     data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
                     id="switcher-store-trigger">
                    <strong>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_group->getName()) ?></span>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
            <?php foreach ($websites as $website) : ?>
                    <li class="switcher-option">
                        <a href="<?= $baseUrl.$website->getDefaultStore()->getCode(); ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: where add this code in stores.phtml file?? ,  should i replace or add it??? if add then what will be the addone position in the code?

Comment: On line no 28 . https://i.imgur.com/3REVykg.png

Comment: sorry this code is not working on my side. can you tell me that where is the value of $websites coming from?? because this is not using in my core file.    in my core file uses $block->getGroups() instead of $websites ...               if i replace it from $block->getGroups() to $websites , then it is not working , please help

Comment: Update my answer

Answer (score 1):

For multi store, you need to create stores

> Stores -> Settings -> All Stores
>
> Create Store View, Store(here you can define store code) and Create Website(for website information)
>
> Then Go to Stores -> Settings -> Configuration
> Here select the store from Scope(left side of side menus) then,
>
> Go to General -> Web -> Base URLs

> Write yours store urls(according to store) for Base URL, Base Link URL, Base URL for Static Vire Files,Base URL for User Media Files.

Do the same for all store and check your store website, it will work.

Hope this will work for you, because multistore we are already using with same concept.

Thank You